# How do i call a function when a tab is selected in a dojo tab container?

Tags: javascript, dojo, tabs

I have a tab container with tabs, that depending on what tab is selected, i would like a function to run.  I have already created the function in Java Script, that will either Hide or Display a window.  The function works fine.  How do i tell the tabs  to run this function?  In the code below, i show in the "Contents" of a tab, a function intitled "hidediv".  I also have a function called "showdiv".  I want to remove it from the contents, and have it run automatically when the tab is selected.  any suggestions?  I do not want it to affect the contents of the tab at all.
Thank you!

```
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Setup">
            <a href="javascript:hidediv()">Hide div</a> 
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is well described in the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html#tabcontainer-events).

Basically, if your TabContainer has id "myTabs", you can do:

```
dojo.subscribe("myTabs-selectChild", function(selected){
    // Do whatever you need here, hidediv() etc..
    console.log(selected.title);
});
```

**Edit:** If you only want something triggered for a particular tab, you can check the title inside the function:

```
dojo.subscribe("myTabs-selectChild", function(selected){
    if(selected.title == "Setup")
    {
       hidediv();
    }
});
```

Perhaps a more elegant way to do it, is to use the ContentPane's onShow event, for example like this:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Setup"
     onShow="hidediv">
     <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry for being a newbie, but where would i insert this code using the example i sent?

Comment: @John You can insert it wherever you want, for example right after your `hidediv` definition.

Comment: I just tried it out, and it works great!  Thank you!  I do have a showdiv i would like to be enabled for just one tab alone.  Is there a way to use the same principles, but apply to just a particular tab title, or id?  Thank you!